# error change price simple product

Tags: syntax-error, magento-1.9, product, price

When I go to a simple product in order to adjust the price I get a error when I save the product.

```
Error
There has been an error processing your request
Decoding failed: Syntax error

Trace:
#0 /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php(659): Zend_Json::decode('', 1)
#1 /data/web/public/app/code/local/Amasty/Conf/Model/Observer.php(145): Mage_Core_Helper_Data->jsonDecode(NULL)
#2 /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): Amasty_Conf_Model_Observer->onSuperProductAttributesPrepareSave(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#3 /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Amasty_Conf_Model_Observer), 'onSuperProductA...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /data/web/public/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#5 /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(670): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#6 /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(725): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->_initProductSave()
#7 /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#8 /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#9 /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /data/web/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /data/web/public/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /data/web/public/index.php(83): Mage::run('dutch', 'store')
#13 {main}

Error log record number: 817468762686
```

I hope someone can tell me what may be the cause.

Best regards,
Michel

Answer (score 0):

Might you be running Magento 1.9 on a PHP7 System?  This answer only applies if you are running PHP7.  If so, try PHP5.6 and see if it still gives you a problem.

If you are on PHP7, it may be because you need the Inchoo_PHP7 Extension.

Have a look here:  https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Magento-1-9-2-create-account-cannot-save-the-customer-error/m-p/42237#M3899

And also here on GitHub, where the extension can also be downloaded: github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7/issues/29

I myself had a similar issue on new order creation at http://www.buildersdepot.com, but it seems connected to PHP7, so updating with a new Incho_PHP7 download seems to have done the trick for me on 8/6/2016, my old version was dated around 4/1/2016.